# Assembly problems with ascii extended characters

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal, extended-ascii

[image]

i want know what to do to solve this issue with the ascii extended characters, i don´t understand why print a strange symbols instead of letter that represent 0x90
i put PutStr  c381
nothing happen
[image]

Comment: *NIX terminals don't support DOS-like "extended" VGA charset or whichever one you expect. If you have your modern OS installed in common way, it's highly likely it is set into UTF8 encoding by default (also in TTY), and also NASM does support UTF8 for source, so you can just write the letters normally into the string, like `db 'ščije'`. (if you will check the resulting machine code - for example use listing-file option with nasm `nasm -l <listing_file.lst>` - the UTF8 is multi-byte encoding with variable byte size per character, so some characters will be assembled as several bytes).

Comment: (if it fails, verify you have UTF8 encoding everywhere, or figure out which other encoding is used... IIRC the NASM is UTF8-only, so strings encoded in other way can't be written directly as text in source code, but you must put them into source as numeric values for `db` or similar... then the `PutStr` API call must support target encoding, and the terminal itself must support target encoding and your terminal font must contain the requested characters .. if all fits, you should see correct character)

Comment: This is not an assembly problem; any program that makes a `write()` system call to write a `0x90` byte to stdout will do the same thing.  (Use `strace ./program` to see what it does, or pipe it into `hexdump -C`).  For example, in bash run `printf '\x90\n'` to do exactly the same thing.  `90 0a` is not a valid UTF-8 multi-byte sequence, so your terminal prints a `�` glyph (a `?` in a diamond).

Comment: I try several times, using the ascii code 160 for "Á", UTF8 hex c3 81 on a putstr but honeslty im pretty new in assembly language so in order to understand what exactly i need to do, could you provide me a small example.(also im using a ubuntu 16. 4, 64 bits)

Comment: @TonyUM Á does not have an ASCII code.  If your terminal is configured to use UTF-8, printing the characters `c3 81` should work.  If it doesn't, please show us your code so we can tell you what the problem is.

Comment: @TonyUM: This has nothing to do with assembly language and everything to do with UTF-8 (which your terminal is expecting) vs. ISO-8859-1 (latin-1) or Windows 1252 (IDK which) extended 8-bit character set which you seem to be looking up codes from.  It would be the same if you wrote a C program with those bytes in a `char array[]` and used stdio `puts`.  Also, I get that you need to show screenshots to illustrate what glyph your terminal printed, but screenshots of your entire desktop are not useful.  Put code in code formatting.  See http://idownvotedbecau.se/imagesofcode.

Comment: You could set your terminal to ISO-8859-1 (right click and use the dropdown, or find the menu entry).  You'll probably want to set `LANG=en_US` in that terminal only (*not* `en_US.UTF-8`) if you do that, so other programs will continue to work well.

Comment: Thank you @PeterCordes this link idownvotedbecau.se/imagesofcode is very useful, to make better questions in the future, but i dont know how to paste the code because everytime i try, the text format changes and paste it in disorder

Comment: SO's built-in text editor has buttons to apply mark-down.  Select your code and click the code-formatting button `{}`, or hit control-k, to indent it by 4 columns.  The http://idownvotedbecau.se/imagesofcode even has a link to https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting which explains this.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with assembly language and everything to do with UTF-8 (which your terminal is expecting) vs. ISO-8859-1 (latin-1) or Windows 1252 (IDK which) extended 8-bit character set which you seem to be looking up codes from. It would be the same if you wrote a C program with those bytes in a `char array[]` and used stdio `puts`.

As @Fuz says, "Á does not have an ASCII code."  ASCII only includes characters from 0..127 (and the low 32 are non-printable) http://www.asciitable.com/.  ***Extended*-ASCII 8-bit character sets only overlap with UTF-8 for code-points from 0 to 127.**

Any program that makes a `write()` system call to write a `0x90` byte to stdout will do the same thing, regardless of what language it was written in.  (Use `strace ./program` to see what yours does, or pipe it into `hexdump -C`). For example, in bash run `printf '\x90\n'` to do exactly the same thing. `90 0a` is not a valid UTF-8 multi-byte sequence, so your terminal prints a � glyph (a ? in a diamond).

---

**You could set your gnome-terminal to ISO-8859-1 or Windows 1252** (right click and use the dropdown, or find the menu entry).  I'm using `konsole`, and it does support both those non-UTF-8 character encodings.

You'll probably want to set `export LANG=en_US` in that terminal only (not the usual `en_US.UTF-8`) if you do that, so other programs will continue to work well.

Or `en_CA` or whatever locale you actually use, just use the non-UTF-8 version of it so `man`'s line-drawing will work, and so will full-screen text things like `gdb`'s TUI `layout reg` mode, or editors like `jed`.

Comment: I finally get it, thank you, i change the profile of the terminal to ISO-8859-1 and use a code like 0xC2